# Symfony2/Twig: can the default delimiters be changed?

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

In Twig, the default delimiters for evaluating expressions is {{ ... }}. Is there any way this can be changed to something else, such as {[{ ... }]}?

Asking since I need to serve AngularJS partials via Twig, and AngularJS uses the exact same delimiters for data binding. I know how to change the delimiters in AngularJS, but as there are hundreds of those and much fewer Twig ones, it would work much better to change the Twig ones instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Twig allows some syntax customization for the block delimiters. It's
>   not recommended to use this feature as templates will be tied with
>   your custom syntax. But for specific projects, it can make sense to
>   change the defaults.
>
> To change the block delimiters, you need to create your own lexer
>   object:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment();

$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
    'tag_comment'   => array('{#', '#}'),
    'tag_block'     => array('{%', '%}'),
    'tag_variable'  => array('{{', '}}'),
    'interpolation' => array('#{', '}'),
));
$twig->setLexer($lexer);
```

Documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you this method :

```
<div ng-app="angularApp">
    {% verbatim %}
    {{ angular_code}}
    {% endverbatim %}
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, even if I accepted Filos answer as it most properly suggested a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> TwigBundle does not provide a configuration for the lexer delimiters
>   as changing them would forbid you to use any templates provided by
>   shared bundles (including the exception templates provided by
>   TwigBundle itself).
>
> However, you could use the raw tag around your angular templates to
>   avoid the pain of escaping all curly braces:
>   http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/raw.html

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony2/kyebufz4M00/8VhF1KWsSAEJ