# How to escape Twig like variables on JS

Tags: javascript, php, templates, twig

I need to escape some JS twig-like variables in a twig template, but I couldn't find anything about how to do that.

This variables are used in a js templating plugin that uses the same pattern as twig for variables

```
tooltipFormat: '<span style="color: {{color}}">&#9679;</span> {{offset:names}}: {{value}}',
```

which is causing the twig rendering to fail

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected) in "path/to/template.twig" at line 116

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is `{{color}}` twig's or JavaScript's now?

Comment: change the twig delimiters.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002996/symfony2-twig-can-the-default-delimiters-be-changed

Comment: They are all javascript...

Comment: Changing the twig delimiters wouldn't solve my problem.. in fact, will just create bigger ones, since the application I'm using this code is in the final stages of development and I would have to change every twig file to the new patterns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html#verbatim) tag, as example, suppose you want to don't process all the code you posted, you can act in this manner:

```
<span style="color: {{color}}">&#9679;</span>{% verbatim %} {{offset:names}}: {{value}}',{% endverbatim %}
```

This will dump the value of the color variable and dump the code surrounded by the verbatim tag